# Find the minimum distance between two points in and 3D configuration

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Consider the L-shaped brick.Suppose an ant start from $A$ and it wants to go to $B$. It can only travel on the surface of the brick. What is the minimum distance that it has to travel??[image]

I tried to open the box and make it a 2D figure but failed. I tried to bash it but also failed. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Just by looking, A to the middle corner to the bottom right corner to B seems like a good candidate with distance of $2\sqrt 2+2$

Comment: **Hint:** Cut the brick in two pieces, one containing $A$ and one containing $B$. Then any path from $A$ to $B$ must cross the cut at some point. Choose a cut so that the shortest distances from $A$ and $B$ to this point are easy to compute.

Answer (score 0):

Convince yourself that the shortest path between $A$ and $B$ is entirely visible in the picture, and does not travel along the leftmost visible square, shaded red in the following picture:

[image]

Fold the top face $F$ up along the blue line so that it is coplanar with $G$ to see that the surface that the shortest path is on is symmetric. So by symmetry there is a shortest path that does not travel along face $G$ or the squares adjacent to it. This means there is a shortest path that only travels along the top $L$-shaped face and the face containg $B$. This you can fold flat to easily see such a shortest path.

Comment: I did the same but the problem is: Suppose I fold the face of B to make it coplanar with F. Now join A,B. It will not be in the plane. This suggests us that the any may have to travel in G as well. This is where I got stucked.

Comment: No; the shortest path will be the shortest path *inside* this elongated $L$-shape. So from $A$ to the inner corner, and from there to $B$.